# Error encountered during deployment

Tags: deployment

I am trying to deploy a field.

In Source org field type is Picklist and in target org field type is Multipicklist.

Why do I get error when I deploy this field. This give some internal salesforce error !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting an error - I would have thought that Salesforce could handle updating a field type.

However, it should be easy enough to deploy:

Either change the field type in the target org to be a standard Picklist or change the field type of the Source org to be a Multi Picklist.

What could end up deciding it is if there is any code in the source/target orgs that depends on the field being one of the Picklist types.